# Can't connect Raspberry Pi server through WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, raspberry-pi

There is a server running on a Raspberry Pi which, when authenticated by a String, sends me back Power Metering Info from Smart Plugs in my house every 30 seconds. This Server opens a socket on port 50333.

I can print the responses to the console in Eclipse with Java and Python by just connecting to it with a standard TCP Socket but when I try and use a websocket in javascript it just won't connect....

I have tried :

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://l92.168.1.27:50333");
```

and:

```
var tcpsock = new TCPSocket("192.168.1.27", "50333");
```

and it doesn't connect....I'm just wondering is my syntax right here or is there possibly some underlying factor that isn't explicitly evident?

Comment: Do you know what web sockets actually is? Are you sure you want bi-directional communication from the JavaScript to the server? Or do you simply want to make requests from JavaScript? What kind of server is being run?

Answer (score 0):

The WebSocket protocol is named a bit misleadingly. It is not a simple TCP socket for use in JS, but a more complex protocol based on Http involving a handshake and a package format. Your server will have to implement that protocol in order for you to be able to connect to it. The RFC is pretty useful: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

It is not that hard to implement, but I bet there are a lot of libraries available that do this for you if you really need it.

Comment: Thanks guys. Ya I was worried that would be the case Wutz....I'm not sure what kind of server is being run Ian, it was developed by a Home Automation company who also have an flash-made WebApp which does what I'm trying to do...

My situation is: I'm currently trying to develop a django based Web App which for starters will display the 3 smart plugs data ( .0002 kW etc.) on a page and update their info which comes in every 30 seconds from their server..I can (in a way) do this from a single python module or java class easily but I'm having trouble translating the process over to a browser

Comment: This may be overkill, but my only idea for this would be to use a proxy, that permanently keeps that TCP connection open and sends incoming data to a WebSocket client. You can either create it yourself, or maybe use the proxy mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705049/connect-to-standard-socket-using-websocket?rq=1

Comment: OK cheers for that. So I don't suppose there would be a way to just use the python module I have that IS getting the responses and passing the string responses to a browser every 30 seconds?

Comment: Only through some sort of proxy, websocket or HTTP.