# Update dynamic content in Browser plugin

Tags: plugins, cross-browser, applet, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a requirement to create a browser plugin. It should be a cross-browser plugin. The look and feel is similar to, say, Ask toolbar. My browser plugin should be able to make calls (using Cisco call control). Internally we will handle that no issue in that. But what is required is that previously we developed website for handling calls, which used java applets to dynamically change the status {Example when there is an incoming call Answer button would get enabled}. Will I be able to achieve it in Browser plugin.

Can I be able to use browser plugin over applet?

Is there any replacement for Java applet in the browser plugin?

Please help me in making a dynamic browser plugin.

---

Update:

I am planning to go for Kango cross-browser extension Framework. I need to know if Kango or any other extension framework support a socket communication where it can listern for sever update.

Thanks.

---

Can I use WebSocket (supported in HTML5) in the browser Extension? I learned that WebSocket method could not communicate directly with ordinary server and it need some changes in the server as well.

Ref: [Connect to standard socket using WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705049/connect-to-standard-socket-using-websocket)

Is there any other way other than WebSocket ?

Is there any open source available for javascript library which uses flash player?

If it could be opensource it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross browser plugin can be developed using some extension development tools such as Cross Rider  or kango . I feel that Cross rider provides good support.

If we are going for Java applet for socket communication, definitely we are ready to face some trouble. Better avoid Java applet.

Socket communication can be achieved in the Web browser using many ways. "Web Socket" is one of them. The only constrain in using it is that it is supported only in HTML5 supporting browser or browser version. IE give support to WebSocket from IE11 only.

Another way to go is using Socket.io . It is having a good way of achieving it by using the available techniques in the client browser. For Example, if the client browser do not have a Flash player (Flash supports socket communication), it uses WebSocket or it "fallback" to available technique supported in browser.

Even node.js is a light weight technique.

The challenge here is we could not communicate with server which support socket with a "websocket" client. We need a proxy, Ref: [Connect to standard socket using WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705049/connect-to-standard-socket-using-websocket)

Hope this should help who need some start on Web Socket communication. If anyone want to add to this I would be very happy.